# Are There Names for Religions?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, religions-and-deities

I've looked around and haven't found anything that satisfied my curiosity on this subject. IRL, we have names for our religions, Buddhism, Judaism, Taoism, etc. But in D&D the focus always seems to be on the name of a specific god.

Are followers of Pelor, for example, practicing Pelorism? Are you a practicing Pelorist?

Recently a player asked for the names of the religions in my homebrew world, and it got me thinking, I only named the gods, and when I went looking for inspiration from the books and the internet, I was at a loss for any info on this topic.

Comment: Related: [Where can I read more about religions in Forgotten Realms?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74081/where-can-i-read-more-about-religions-in-forgotten-realms)

Comment: Also, are you asking about the lore of a particular setting?

Comment: @V2Blast not really looking for any specific setting, its more just research in an effort to do some worldbuilding for my homebrew world. I feel like having a few examples of how D&D as a whole has named things it might spark inspiration for me to go from the names of gods/pantheons to descriptors and titles for my players to latch on to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the appropriate adjectives spread around in various products, for example 2e *Faiths and Avatars* is a good source for the Forgotten Realms. Specifically for Pelor (who is one of the Powers of Oerth), the adjective used in a dedicated [article in Dragon #346](https://archive.org/stream/DragonMagazine260_201801/DragonMagazine346#page/n11/mode/2up) was Pelorian.

There are also names for specific orders and sects under the organised hierarchy of various churches. For example, the Risen Sun heresy rose amongst The Brotherhood of the Glorious Sun sect of the Church of Lathander. More examples like this can be found on the FR fandom website, under the title [Category: Religious organizations](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Religious_organizations) (thanks to @V2Blast for the pointer).

Yet I feel your question might be missing a subtle point. The religion in most D&D campaign worlds is polytheistic/pantheistic and most people do not worship a single deity. Consider the religion of the ancient Romans, we simply call it Roman religion. Likewise, the people of Faerûn mostly follow the Faerunian pantheon. Quoting Ed Greenwood on [twitter](https://twitter.com/TheEdVerse/status/1125904397064654850):

> Remember, the Realms is pantheistic, not mono-theistic: only clerics, paladins, and a few "fanatics" worship only one god. Most folks worship all the gods of their race, but about a third of that "most" devote most of their worship to a handful of gods.

Comment: Thanks for the leads! And also, it DID escape me that these things are pantheistic, i will also research names for pantheistic religions. We might call it the "roman religion" but i am now curious if they had a name for it when it was still extant.

Comment: Good answer. I was also going to point out that, to the extent that there are basically "sects" of religions, they're mostly organized around specific religious organizations, at least in the Forgotten Realms. [There's a category for religious organizations on the FR wiki.](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Religious_organizations) Many of them are named, though some are simply "Church of [X]". Things may be different in other settings.

Comment: You don’t mean pantheistic, you mean polytheistic. Pantheism is the belief that God is the Universe. Polytheism is the belief in many gods.

Comment: @DaleM: I had used the word by Greenwood. It is not really incorrect, according to Merriam-Webster pantheism also means: "the worship of all gods of different creeds, cults, or peoples indifferently; toleration of worship of all gods (as at certain periods of the Roman empire)". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pantheism

I still edited and added the word polytheistic. Thanks for the comment.